# jQuery Cycle2 – overlay size to match slide's image size

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, jquery-cycle

I'm trying to use jQuery to get the current slide's image size in a Cycle2 slideshow.

This is so I can set the size of an overlay div (`.overlay`) that appears on .hover(). As you'll see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/approach/76uJm/3/), it is only getting the size from the first image. The images will be responsive too, so `.overlay` will also need to update it's size based on any window resizing.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/approach/76uJm/3/) link again, and the full code:

```
var imgwidth = $('.cycle-slide img').width();
var imgheight = $('.cycle-slide img').height();

$('.cycle-slide').hover(function () {        
    $('.overlay', this).css('width', imgwidth).css('height', imgheight).fadeIn();
    }, function() {
    $('.overlay', this).fadeOut();
});
```

How can I get `.overlay` to match each slide's image size?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably hook into the `cycle-after` event to set the width.. Something similar to this:

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-after', function(event, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag) {
    $('.overlay', this).css({'width':$('img',incomingSlideEl).css('width'), 'height': $('img',incomingSlideEl).css('height')});
});


$('.cycle-slide').hover(function () {        
    $('.overlay', this).show();
    }, function() {
    $('.overlay', this).fadeOut();
});
```

The only thing you may have to do is set the width and height of the first overlay outside the event because I don't think it is fired on the first slide.

Comment: Your code and suggestion work perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it worked out.  Here is the api for the events.  There are quite a few and if you use the plugin a bit, they come in real handy:  http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/api/#events